# If a value in specific column is contained in the list,I want to check it in another column

Tags: python, pandas

case : if a value in "nextday_date" column is contained in holiday_date_list, i want to check it in "nextday_holiday" as 1

below code is correct. but this code can be more concise?

```
train = pd.read_csv("./train.csv")
holiday_date_list = [a, b, c, d]

idx = [idx for idx, value in enumerate(train["nextday_date"]) if value in holiday_date_list]

train.loc[idx, "nextday_holiday"] = 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `train['nextday_date'].isin(train['nextday_holiday']).astype(int)`..?

Comment: Thank you ! this comment is really helpful ! I changed code like this. train["nextday_holiday"] = train["nextday_date"].isin(holiday_date_list).astype(int) @anky_91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["11","2", "6"], ["12","4", "2"], ["13","3", "4"]],
             columns=["ix","a", "b"])

    ix  a   b
0   11  2   6
1   12  4   2
2   13  3   4
```

Check if values in a is contained in values in b:

```
df['res']=df.a.isin(df.b).astype(int)
>>df

    ix  a   b   res
0   11  2   6   1
1   12  4   2   1
2   13  3   4   0
```

This works for list too.

Comment: Thanks ! I wanted to know .isin(). I changed like this. train["nextday_holiday"] = train["nextday_date"].isin(holiday_date_list).astype(int)